# Automated test for install script

Tags: linux, chroot, testing, sandbox

I'm writing an install script for an appliance that modifies system config files under `/etc` (amongst other things). How can I test this script non-destructively?

Ideally I would like to run the script in a pseudo-sandbox that provides a layer over the existing filesystem, and then see examine any changed files afterwards.

I'm not worried about the script being intentionally malicious, but would like to protect against system files being modified or deleted in any way.

Comment: are you using `install` helpers?

Comment: @Braiam no, should I be? Link?

Comment: @Braiam are you referring to a specific tool, or to distro package management tools? Currently the software this script installs is not packaged, but that would be the next logical step. Target platform is Ubuntu.

Comment: `install` is included in the `coreutils` package. You should be able to read the manual using `info coreutils 'install invocation'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Docker](https://www.docker.io/) to create an OS in a container image, then run the install script in the activated container. Afterwards you can use the `docker diff` command to see what files it changed in the container. The container is isolated from the host, so your real `/etc` files would be unaffected.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll take a look. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Your best environment would be a local vm with a small filesystem mounted from a file within your host system.

This allows you to take a copy of the vm file-system after vm is initally installed.

Then you can reset the file system, back to saved copy, after you have run a test of your install on the vm. So you can repeat your test.

Comment: This is a good idea and had occurred to me, but I'm not sure which virtual machine software would be most suitable. Any recommendations? Scriptable would be a big advantage

Comment: Tks, vmware/virtualbox are only 2 I've used, never got around to trying qemu, xen, hmmn ... I'm not an expert more a user, that would make a good new question question though ... :-)